# Best Practices - RoR 4 Heroku - Cron to fill database each hour from external API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, postgresql, heroku, amazon-ec2

I have to call externals API to fill my database, hosted on Heroku each hours.

For this purpose, I've a ruby script that get all the data from externals API and output on the stdout. Now, I would like to store those results in my database, I have differents ways to do it (Please let a comment if you know a better way).

**What I have (Constraints) :**

- Ruby on Rails Application running on Heroku
- PG Database hosted on Heroku
- "Cars" model, with "Title", "Description", "Price" attributes, and 1 other nested attribute from "Users" Model (So same schema in PG).
- Ruby Script that query the differents externals API
- Ruby Script have to be called each hours / 2 hours / days. The script is going to run for about 10 minutes -> 2 hours depending of the number of results

**My 3 differents ways to do it :**

- Running the script on a EC2 Instance, and fill my database with external login directly to the database, not by the Ruby on Rails REST API.
  The problem is that it never ask for the Ruby on Rails validators, so for example if my database changed, or if I have to validate some data, it won't.
- Running the script on a EC2 Instance, and fill my database with cll to my RoR REST API, so filling the data with JSON / XML. The problem is that I think if I have > 1000 calls from the API, it can make my dynos suffer with high load.
- Running my script on a specific dyno on Heroku (I need some informations, I can't find some informations on Heroku)
- (Please let a comment if you know a better way)

What do you think ? I need something really evolutive, if tomorrow i change my "Cars" model, everything has to be easy to make the switch between old and new model.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think that the best approach would be to use a background process to perform the work. Gems like http://sidekiq.org/ and DelayedJob all have the ability to schedule jobs (which then reschedule themselves for 2 hours later in your case).

On Heroku, workers run seperate to your web dynos so won't interfere with the performance it also keeps things simple in that you don't need to expose an API since you'll have direct access to your models from the worker.

There are plenty of Heroku docs on this subject;

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job

Comment: Thank you for your answer, never noticed that workers can access models. Simple !

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by writing your scripts as a Rake tasks and then use Heroku Scheduler to schedule your task(s) to run at specific intervals:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler

You can separate your tasks by schedule if you have multiple, and then just add multiple schedulers. They run in [one-off dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos) (which you pay for at the normal rate), and since they're running from the same code base can leverage all your existing app code (models, libs, etc).